# Java type casting. Logic behind (String), .toString() and "" + int

Tags: java, string, casting, tostring

Java is a strongly typed language. Hence, less bugs in compiled code and better readability at a cost of slower coding. Hence, explicit type casting is required, this part is clear.

What is the difference between these snippets:

```
(String)myInt // obviously doesn't compile
Integer.toString(myInt)
"" + myInt
```

Is it purely for historical reasons, or there is some meaning behind it?
Which method is appropriate?

Comment: Actually, where Java's type system is sound/sufficient, type *casting* is the one thing you shouldn't have to do.

Comment: In this case, what is (String)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As was mentioned before, `(String) myInt` is a typecast. In Java, we can either cast within primitives or upwards in the object-hierarchy. Since `int` is a primitive and `String` is an object, we have a problem. Even [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) cannot resolve this dilemma since `Integer` and `String` do not stand in an inheritance-relationship. Therefore, it is perfectly plausible for `(String) myInt` to result in a compilation error.

The semantics of `Integer.toString(myInt)` and `"" + myInt` are identical. The specifics, however, are different.

When executing `Integer.toString(myInt)`, a new `String` is constructed, containing a String-representation of `myInt`.

When executing `"" + myInt`, Java first constructs a global `String`-constant, having the value `""` (this is done by the JVM, we do not see this <sup>1</sup>). The lexer demands a `String` on the right side of `+` since it found a `String` on the left side of `+`. For primitives, the JVM "knows" how to convert them into `String`s. For objects, `toString()` is called. Since `Object` has this method and each class is (at least implicitly) derived from `Object`, each object is guaranteed to have a `toString()` method. This is the second `String` constructed. Since [`String`s are immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), the JVM might create a third `String`, representing the concatenation of the first two `String`s<sup>2</sup>.

---

**Epilogue**

And then, at execution time, the JIT-compiler strikes and most of this might be irrelevant since the JIT-optimized versions of both variants may look equal. Or not. Or maybe only sometimes. JIT does funny stuff. So in the end it is more a question of personal style than performance :)

---

<sup>1</sup> This is actually a lie. When writing

```
String s1 = "";
String s2 = "";
System.out.println(s1 == s2);
```

one will observe that the result is `true`, whereas `false` is expected. This is due to the fact that the JVM creates a pool for all `String` constants to save some memory.

<sup>2</sup> It is well possible that the JVM "recognizes" that `something + "" == "" + something == something` and therefore does not create this third `String`. I did neither test nor research this.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to prefer `String.valueOf(int)`, myself, but yes there are multiple paths to get there.

In general, if you're converting the `int` to a `String` *in isolation*, you want `Integer.toString(int)`, `String.valueOf(int)`, or similar.

Your `"" + myInt` will be markedly less efficient than the above (though it usually doesn't matter): It compiles to creating a new `StringBuilder`, then appending `""` to it, then appending the `int` to it (which calls one of the methods above to convert it to a string first), and then getting the `String` from the `StringBuilder`. So while you might do it as part of an overall concatenation operation, on its own it's pretty poor.

Your `(String)` example doesn't work: You can't just cast an `int` to a `String`, you'll get a compile-time "incompatible types" error.

Answer (score 3):

It's a language feature that "officially" overloads the `+` operator such that

```
"" + myInt
```

is compiled as if it were:

```
new StringBuilder().append("").append(myInt).toString();
```

and `StringBuilder#append()` (ultimately) calls `String.valueOf()` to render `myInt`.

This feature was done presumably because if they didn't, no one would use the language - it would just be too painful.

Comment: overloads the + operator - that explains the mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

`(String)` - this works only on strings, so if you have this:

```
Object test = "test";
String test2 = (String) test;
```

It will work (since `Object` test will be of `String` type).

If you have something like this:

```
Integer test = new Integer(2);
String test2 = (String) test;
```

You get `ClassCastException`.

```
Integer.toString(myInt)
```

This is what it does:

```
 public static String  toString(int i) {
         if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
             return "-2147483648";
         int size = (i < 0) ? stringSize(-i) + 1 : stringSize(i);
         char[] buf = new char[size];
         getChars(i, size, buf);
         return new String(0, size, buf);
     }
```

It just turns your number to string char by char.

```
"" + myInt
```

This will tell compiler that you want to join things as string, not add two numbers (since string is first, it will go with joining strings). myInt will be turn into the string, or if it is an object, it will call `toString()` method from it.

Also, make sure you read about String pool in JVM, to know what it will do here. In situations like this it can end up creating a lot of temporary strings (if you have a lot of `+`; avoid that by using `StringBuilder`).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, lets compare `(String)val` and `val.toString()`.

The key difference in those two statements is that casting is made **by compiler** while `toString()` method is usually implemented **by programmer**. That said, you can cast only if value extends `String` and you can implement `toString()` of any class. `toString()` works just like any other method and nothing(almost) special about it.

Now let's take a look at `""+int`. I personally consider this as anti-pattern, because it's compiled in to wildly unefficient code. A lot of useless objects being created; in short: the result is similiar with manually concatenating few string literals with `StringBuilder`. Also, in statements like `""+var` `var` does not extends `String`, `toString()` implicitly called.

I hope this was clear.